# What does "self" mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, keyword, self

I read [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/js-ref/article.php/3471031/Special-Edition-Using-HTML-4-JavaScript-Keyword-Reference.htm) that "*self  Refers to the current window or form*".

Self does not seem to refer to the current form in this case:

```
<form><input type="text" onkeyup="alert(self.foo.value)" name="foo"></form>
```

However in this case it works (referring to the window):

```
<form><input type="text" onkeyup="alert(self.document.forms[0].foo.value)" name="foo"></form>
```

So when would you use the `self` DOM property over just `window`?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that self is not a keyword, to avoid confusion. self is a property of window (properties are members of objects, keywords are essentially what makes up the programming language itself, such as "if" and "for")

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  i have never used js outside of the DOM.

Comment: Never trust HTML Goodies, it is **awful**. It makes W3Schools look good.

Comment: I modified the question in light of answers pointing out self is not in fact a key word.  I'm still curious why it exists.

Comment: I've no idea where they got the idea that the `self` global (`window` property) would ever point to a form. It's utter tosh. Maybe they got it confused with what `this` points to in `form onsubmit`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> For all windows, the `self` and `window`
>   properties of a `window` object are
>   synonyms for the current window, and
>   you can optionally use them to refer
>   to the current window. For example,
>   you can close the current window by
>   calling the `close` method of either
>   `window` or `self`. You can use these
>   properties to make your code more
>   readable or to disambiguate the
>   property reference `self.status` from a
>   form called `status`.

Comment: so I guess self == window.  The link I posted is very misleading.  If that is a quote could you post the source?

Comment: Original source http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/window.htm. Modern source http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#dom-self

Answer (score 15):

Other replies have pointed out that `self` is not going to refer to the `FORM` and that `self` is `window`. They're right; `self` *is* `window`. Well, except when it isn't. In either IE6 or IE7 (forgot), `self.onload` would not fire, though `window.onload` would.

All official versions of IE (and even IE9pr3) have an odd, intransitive implementation of `==` with these host objects. Using `==` to compare either `window` or `self` to a node in the document, the result is `true`.

**IE Oddities**

```
alert(self == document.body); // true
alert(document.body == self); // false
alert(window == self); // true
alert(window === self); //false
var b = document.createElement("b");
alert(window == b); // false
alert(window == document.body.appendChild(b)); // true
alert(window == document.body.removeChild(b)); // false
```

Answer (score 11):

`self` is not a reserved keyword or standard type, but has become a defacto standard name when for keeping reference to an object for closures.

Here we create a closure to pass to `setTimeout()`. When that closure is executed, `this` will refer to the global object. To keep a reference to the `foo` object `doLater` was originally called on, a var named `self` is used. It could be anything but 'self' has meaningful semantics.

```
Foo.prototype.doLater = function() {
  var self = this; // current object

  window.setTimeout(function() { self.doSomething(); }, 1000);
}

new Foo().doLater();
```

Comment: While this works, I suggest that the more idiomatic JavaScript solution would be `Foo.prototype.doLater = function() { setTimeout(function() { this.doSomething(); }.bind(this), 1000); };`

Answer (score 10):

**self** refers to the **global scope** - 
If the context is a window it will refer to window.self, while in case of a non-windowed context it will refer to the global scope of that context (e.g. in service worker code, self refers to the worker global scope).

self refers to the global scope of a context:

- window context
- worker context (support for multiple workers for the same webapp is being worked on).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self

Answer (score 6):

Never, unless I wanted to create a `self` variable in the scope of a function referring to the context for later reference,

```
function Constructor() {
    var self = this;
}
```

You should use `this` to refer to the element at hand, not `self`. In global scope though `this` is a reference to `window`, and `self` is also `window`.