# When to use self in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that calls like `setTimeout()` work either as :

`self.keyword()`

or just on their own e.g. `keyword()`.

What is the different between the two calls?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216428/self-keyword-in-javascript

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`self` *can* refer to the window object, but typically that's not the case here.  You'll see this commonly above that `setTimeout()`:

```
var self = this;
```

They're keeping a reference to the **current object**, so later when you call `self.keyword()` you're calling that method *on that object*, not any other.

Say you have for example images in the page you wanted to rotate every 2 seconds...you'd want each of those 3 timers to refer to *their own* methods.  If they use `this` directly, it would (most of the time) refer to `window` and not the current object, whereas passing another variable in maintains the current reference.

Comment: But a method like setTimeout is global and provided by the JVM rather than an object?

Comment: @Konrad - `setTimeout()` is a global function itself, but it can execute any function, for example: `setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);` or `setTimeout(function() { alert(this); }, 1000);`

Answer (score 14):

It works with `setTimeout` because of two conditions in the browser:

- All global variables are properties of the `window` object. That means that `window` has a property `setTimeout` (`window.setTimeout`).
- The `window` object has a property called `self` that points to itself.

As you can access the properties of `window` without explicitly writing `window` (that is what makes the global variables global), both calls work: `setTimeout()` will look up the property `setTimeout()` on the window object. `self.setTimeout()` will look up the property `self` on the `window` object, which is the window object itself.

So if you call `self.setTimeout()` it is the same as `window.self.setTimeout()` which is the same as `window.setTimeout()` which again is the same as `setTimeout()`.

*Note: This only works if there is no variable `self` defined in the current scope that shadows the global `self`.*

This works with *any* symbol (meaning variable or function) defined in the global scope. You can test it yourself:

```
alert(window.self);
```

and

```
alert(self);
```

should both alert

```
[object Window]
```

Comment: Re your first point, it's really the other way round: `setTimeout` is a method of the `window` object that happens to be appear to be global because `window` points to the global object.

Comment: @Tim Down: Thank you for clarification. I always get a bit confused when it is about global and window object ;)

Answer (score 8):

Every property and method on `window` object can be called with or without 'window.'.

and

> self is a read-only property on window object that returns the window itself (MDN)

so

`setTimeout()`

`window.setTimeout()`

`window.self.setTimeout()`

`self.setTimeout()`

are all same thing.

The main advantage of doing `self.setTimeout()` instead of `window.setTimeout()` or any other way is that, if you run some code that calls `window.setTimeout()` inside WebWorker, it will fail but the `self.setTimeout()` will work both in web workers and the browser context. So if you are writing a library that should work both on main window's scope and the web worker, we should prefer using `self.`

`self` always refer to the GlobalScope which in case of browser mode is `window` and inside web workers is `WorkerGlobalScope'

Comment: useful point about the difference when running in a WebWorker

Comment: self.self.self.self.self...