# jquery $(this).parents('.cssClassName') only finds window in IE, but works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have the following jquery code:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.del', function () {
        var self = $(this);
        parent = self.parents('.transportRow');
        parent.remove();
    });
});
```

When i click a link with the class "del" inside a div with the class "transportRow" the div should be removed.

This is working fine in Webkit and Firefox, but not in IE

I get an error that tells me that the object does not support the property or method "remove".

When i inspect it in the debugger, parent seems to be the window, not the div element.

Does anybody know how to get this script running in IE?

Comment: Try changing `self` to some other name, in JavaScript, `self` is `window`

Comment: @ranganadh That's not always the case. `self` can be set to anything. Typically, you'll see `var self = this;`. In this case `self` is based on the current context of `this`. It could be the window, but it does not have to be. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309516/when-to-use-self-in-javascript#answer-3309557) answer for reference...

Comment: what version please ...

Comment: Having you tried logging `self` and `parent`? Try `console.log(self);` and `console.log(parent);` to see what the values contain.

Comment: Strangely, this seems to fix it: `var parent = self.parents('.transportRow');`  (tested IE10) EDIT: looks like global `parent` variable refers to Window on IE10 (other ???)

Comment: @War10ck In IE11, self works like a normal variable, but I've no idea about lower versions of IE

Comment: @ranganadh Should work like a normal variable in all version of IE. I've seen the `var self = this;` syntax a lot in MV* frameworks like Knockoutjs. It's very common and works across all browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `parent` without `var` you refer to the global variable `parent` a.k.a. the `parent` property on the global (`window`) object.

In IE the [`window.parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property is readonly (in reality it is the [*property attribute*](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.1) `[[Writable]]` of the property that is set to `false` or not set at all).

Changing the row:

```
parent = self.parents('.transportRow');
```

to

```
var parent = self.parents('.transportRow');
```

should do the trick. Or change names.

Crockford talks about this issue and recommends using `that` instead of `self`. This advice is also applicable on `parent` I say.

Comment: **+1** On mentioning `that`, Even though comments above that explained the legitimacy of using self; I see no reason to put yourself & code in that situation where it still '*could*' become a problem through JavaScript's quirky scoping (Although it's entirely preference)