# AngularJS 1.6 + ES6 - Returning jquery ui-grid callback data to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm defining a jquery ui-grid component in my controller, the minified example of which is shown below:

```
class myController {
    constructor($scope) {        

        this.$scope = $scope; 

        this.Grid = {                               

            selectionSettings:{
                clientHandler:function(key,object,data){
                    console.log(key);
                    console.log(object);
                    console.log(data);                    
                    console.log(this);
                    return data;                        
                    //the scope of this function is different from the controller scope.                          
                    }              
           }
       }

       receiver(data){
             doSomething(data);
       }
    ...
```

The idea is that when I select an entry within the grid, the function within clientHandler is fired. I then want this function to **pass that data to the receiver function** in this class.

But since this `clientHandler` function and `receiver()` **are in different scopes**, I'm not able to do so directly using the `this` keyword.

Other answers on stackoverflow recommend using the `$scope` object to accomplish the same, but I'm not able to do so.

What is needed to make the `clientHandler` function call `receiver()` ?

Any guidance is earnestly welcomed. Thanks

Comment: Either that (call `receiver` yourself) or [save `this` in a `self` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309516/when-to-use-self-in-javascript).

Comment: That worked. Thanks

Comment: While I'm able to see the change on my browser console, I'm not able to propagate the change caused by callbackHandler on my UI. I'm trying to call the `$doCheck()` lifecycle hook manually to reflect the same, but it doesn't make any difference. Which lifecycle hook can propagate this change to the UI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Adelin for the heads-up

Here's the final working code:

```
class dashboardController {
    constructor(dashboardService, $scope) {
        this.$scope = $scope;      

        var self = this;

        this.Grid = {

            selectionSettings:{                
               clientHandler:function(key,object,data){
                   self.receiver(data);                 
            }                
        }

        receiver(data){
             this.selected = data;
             this.$scope.$apply(); //to propagate the change to the UI, if needed
         }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 arrow functions exist to provide lexical `this` and avoid `self = this` trick, which is generally unnecessary in ES6:

```
clientHandler: (key,object,data) => {
  this.receiver(data);   
}
```

Comment: I tried this - didn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: `var self = this` is antipattern in ES6. Arrow functions are supposed to replace it entirely. The code in the answer is idiomatic equivalent to the one you've posted.