# JS how to avoid using "this"

Tags: javascript, this

I recently watched a youtube tutorial, and the guy did something interesting in the series (it's node.js game tutorials by Raining Chain). His constructor looks like this:

```
const MakeStuff = function(param1, param2) {
  const self = {};
  self._param1 = param1;
  self._param2 = param2;
  // and so on...
  return self;
}

const someStuff = MakeStuff(param1, param2);
```

I then checked google for what "self" meant and it found out it's something similar to "this"... It's really confusing me now. At first I thought he's just naming it "self" to mimic "this", but avoid using it.

Also, JSLint really hates "this", and I hate to dumb down JSLint and disable or edit options (ocd), so I'm trying to figure out how am I gonna use classes, and avoid using "this" inside classes constructor.

I figured I'd copy/paste my class function in babeljs and see what the class syntax actually does under the hood, but I got even more confused.

I have around 2k lines of code in my game, and 1.5k are just classes with getters, setters and static methods.

What does the code above actually do? What does self mean? Can I use JS classes and avoid using "this" in constructors? Why does JSLint even hate "this"? Should I rework my code using the example above and bind getters, setters and static methods using prototype?

Thanks!

Comment: In this instance, `self` is just a variable that's initially assigned as a blank Object, and then has a few fields attached to it before being returned.  There's nothing _special_ about calling it `self` instead of `thing` or `mine` or any other name.  Within the scope of the function, it is just a label, and when you return it, it just becomes what ever you assigned it to (`someStuff` in this case).

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875767/difference-between-this-and-self-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is one of the important aspects of JavaScript but one of the most poorly understood. It is absolutely essential to understand to do any Object Oriented Programming within JS which is essential to game design.

I would recommend learning about scope and how `this` applies to different things in different scopes.

- http://web.archive.org/web/20110725013125/http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
- https://javascriptplayground.com/javascript-variable-scope-this/
- http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Essentially when you run a function such as

> function window_scope() {
>
> this.foobar;
>
> }

`this` is the `window` in browsers or whatever variable is defined as the global scope. Meaning `this.foobar` is equal to `window.foobar`

When you do `new` while calling a function such as `var newfoo = new foo()`

> function foo() {
>
> this.foobar;
>
> }

`this` has suddenly become a reference to `newfoo`.  Meaning `this.foobar` is equal to `newfoo.foobar` This allows you to make objects that don't need a reference to the actual local variable `newfoo`

Comment: Very useful links provided. I couldn't decide which one to pick as an answer as they are all equally good answers. Thanks everybody for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, self is used by other languages in place of js' `this`; it is a reference to the instance's context. In this use case, he's not writing a constructor, but a factory. `self` is little more than a naming convention here. It would make no difference if he wrote:

```
const MakeStuff = function(param1, param2) {
  const obj = {};
  obj._param1 = param1;
  obj._param2 = param2;
  // and so on...
  return obj;
}

const someStuff = MakeStuff(param1, param2);
```

Also, +1 to brk for mentioning that `self`, unless re-set, references `window`.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the code above actually do?

```js
const MakeStuff = function(param1, param2) {
  const self = {};
  console.log(self);
  self._param1 = param1;
  self._param2 = param2;
  // and so on...
  return self;
}

const someStuff = MakeStuff(1, 2);
console.log(someStuff)
```

This above code simply calls a function which accepts two parameter and return an object.`self` inside this function is merely a variable

> What does self mean?

Unless specifically set [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) refers to the `window` object.But in the above function `const self` is not `window.self`

```js
console.log(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me `MakeStuff` is just a function, not a constructor. And `self` doesn't have anything to do with `this` in the code you provided. Here it's just a variable inside the function that gets assigned some keys and elements `param1` and `param2`.

```
const MakeStuff = function(param1, param2) {
  const returnedElement = {};
  returnedElement ._param1 = param1;
  returnedElement ._param2 = param2;
  // and so on...
  return returnedElement ;
}

const someStuff = MakeStuff(param1, param2);
```

Sometimes you will need to use `self` (some use `that`) to access `this` but within another scope.

A great explanation you can find on [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3309557/6331369) is:

> `var self = this;`
>
> [This is] keeping a reference to the **current object**, so later when you call [`self`] you're calling that method *on that object*, not any other.

Answer (score 0):

in your case self is just the name of an constant.