# jsDoc Toolkit methods, fields and properties don't show when I use a self var

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Toolkit

I'm trying to document my classes but i'm using a "self" var to expose only the public methods.

jsDoc can find the class name, but can't find the methods, fields, properties, etc...

this is 1 of my classes:

Anny suggestion how I should approach this?

```
(function(App){
  /** @class The ViewModel for the EventView */
  App.ViewModels.EventsViewModel = function(service) {

    var self = {};

    /** Observable array containing events */
    self.events = new ko.observableArray();

    /** Call the fetchEvents method on the service */
    self.refreshEvents = function(e){
        $('.refreshBtn').changeIcon('refreshing');
        service.fetchEvents();
    }
    /** subscribe on the service->currentEvents var
      * on change update the events in this viewmodel
      * set the refesh butting is set to refresh (instead of refreashing) */
    service.currentEvents.subscribe(
        function(newValue){
            self.events(newValue);
            $('.refreshBtn').changeIcon('refresh');
        }
    );
    /** function for a timespan string ex: "10:00 - 14:00"
      * Date inputs should be of ISO-8601 Date format  */
    self.toTimeString= function(/* String */ start,/* String */ end)/* String */
    {
        var out = "";
        try
        {
            out =(start!=null && end!=null)? Util.IsoDateParse(start).format("HH:MM") + " - " + Util.IsoDateParse(end).format("HH:MM") : ""
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            out ="Error during toTimeString.\n\n";
            out+="Error description: " + err + "\n\n";
        }
        return out;
    }

    /** Call the fetchEvents method on the service */
    self.refreshEvents();

    return self;
  };
})(App)
```

ps: I'm using Knockoutjs & jQueryMobile

**EDIT:**

Thanks! Almost there... I tried to do something like this:

```
/** @memberOf App.ViewModels.EventsViewModel#
  * @field * @description Observable array containing events */
self.events = new ko.observableArray();
```

jsDoc shows it like "self.events" instead of "events"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `memberOf` tag([TagMemberOf](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagMemberOf)). And since `App.ViewModels.EventsViewModel` is declared in an anonymous function you may need to use the `name` tag([TagName](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagName)) to scope it as global.

Edit:

Try:

```
/** @memberOf App.ViewModels.EventsViewModel#
  * @field
  * @description Observable array containing events
  * @name events
  */
self.events = new ko.observableArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost there...

I tried to do something like this:
`/** @memberOf App.ViewModels.EventsViewModel#
  *  @field
  *  @description Observable array containing events */
self.events = new ko.observableArray();`

jsDoc shows it like "self.events" instead of "events"

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple constructor.
Use 'this' instead 'self'.

JsDoc understand members of 'this'

If you want to use other name than 'this', you can add alternative

```
var StackOverflow = function(){
  /** Alternative */
  var me = this;

  /**
  * Default rating
  * @type {number}
  */
  this.rating = 10;

  /** Load Happy New Year: increase rating */
  this.loadNewYear = function() {
    $.ajax().done(function(){
      me.rating = 100500;
    });
  };
};
```

PS: do not use 'self': https://stackoverflow.com/a/3216464/1197421

Use 'me' or something else.