# self is not a reserved word in javascript --so how it it is used w/o being defined in my script?

Tags: javascript

I have the hang of basic javascript syntax and am working to understand the language at a deeper level. I am looking at this line of code from the `elizabot.js` file in the elizabot.js library:

```
var global=ElizaBot.prototype.global=self;
```

1. I think that this is setting the global property of the prototype for the Elizabot object equal to "self."  Am I understanding the meaning of that line correctly?
2. Self does not seem to be a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in javascript. But if I search the Elizabot.js file for the word "self" I can't find it. Is there some special meaning for the word self in javascript? I can't find the declaration.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216428/self-property-in-javascript

Comment: I just popped open the console and typed "self" and it returned the Window. I'm using Chrome, so I'm not sure if that's standard across the board, but yeah! Apparently it is defined.

Comment: `self` is refering to `window.self`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self.  Here's the docs about `window`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: self is typically the only global handle when window is not present like in node.js, webwrokers, etc.

Comment: @dandavis ```self``` is undefined in nodejs. nodejs uses ```global``` for the global namespace object

Comment: @cbayram: you're right. i must have been thinking about something else... still webworkers alone makes it more valuable than window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the browser, `self` refers to the global `window` object

ElizaBot is a function that is setting its **global** property to the window object for all instances of ElizaBot created (through prototype)

```
var global = ElizaBot.prototype.global=self;
function ElizaBot(){
  console.warn(this.global == self);
  console.warn(this.global == window);
  console.warn(self == window);
  console.warn(self.self.self.window.self == this.global.self.window);
  // I can go on forever :) time to stop
}
new ElizaBot();
new ElizaBot();
```

Comment: Apparently, and much to my surprise, you're right (in Chromium 28/Ubuntu 12.10 at least).

Comment: @cbayram and it is also setting the value of the var global to the global property of the eliza function, right? There are two assignments going on in that one line of code.

Comment: @abe3 yes ```var global``` is also set to self/window/ElizaBot.prototype.global object, all which are references to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

In a browser (not in generic javascript), `self` is a property of the `window` object that contains the value of the current `window`.  Since all properties of the `window` object are accessible as global variables, you can refer to just `self` and it will contain a reference to the current document's window.

Thus, in your code:

```
var global=ElizaBot.prototype.global=self;
```

is assigning to both `ElizaBot.prototype.global` and to the variable `global` a reference to the current `window` object.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self) for info on `window.self` which is also accessible as just `self`.

---

FYI, all of these assignments seem superfluous since the current window object is generally accessible in other ways and need not be stored separately.

Comment: Agree, don't understand the downvote for a thorough answer with references. Upvote.